# Cauchy integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am evaluating

```
Integrate[1/(1 + 3*cosin(x)*cosin(x)), {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

in *Mathematica*, which should give me `Pi`, but instead I got

```
ConditionalExpression[(
 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[3] cosin \[Pi]] - I (Log[-I cosin] - Log[I cosin]))/(
 Sqrt[3] cosin), 
 Re[1/cosin] == 0 && -Sqrt[3] \[Pi] <= Im[1/cosin] <= Sqrt[3] \[Pi]]
```

which I cannot interpret at all.

Could somebody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @yarchik, in this case, your correction obscured one of the OP's problems, in that he did not use the correct syntax.

Comment: @J.M. I overlooked that `cosin(x) ` was all around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your variables before you run and "cosine" isn't recognized by *Mathematica*. You need to use [`Cos[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cos.html).

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Integrate[1/(1 + 3 Cos[x] Cos[x]), {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

> Pi

In regard to your follow-up question in the comments about the following equation:

$$1/(1 - Cos[x] - I (1/3) Sin[x])$$

The integral doesn't converge with the region `{x,-Pi,Pi}` but you can evaluate the Cauchy principal value by using the [`PrincipalValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrincipalValue.html) option.

```
Integrate[1/(1 - Cos[x] - I (1/3) Sin[x]), {x, -Pi, Pi}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

> 3 Pi

Comment: thanks. Another example I tried is Integrate[1/(1 - cosin[x] - I*(1/3)*sin[x]), {x, -Pi, Pi}] , which should return 3 Pi, but mathematica only outputs the integral formula. What's wrong?

Comment: @mao, use `Cos[x]` instead of `cosin[x]`; the latter is not known to *Mathematica*.

Comment: @mao. And `Sin[x]` instead of `sin[x]`.

Comment: @maomao I updated the answer with your comment question